# How to typecast OMstring to char *

Tags: c++, rhapsody

I am using Rhapsody OMString and my code need to typecast OMstring to char *

```
 reader.readStream((unsigned char *)MachineType,machineTypeDataSize);  // MachineType is OMString
```

Is it possible to typecast OMString to char *

Comment: As far as I remember from my Rhapsody days, there was no real benefit to using `OMString` over `std::string`. Are you absolutely sure you need to use it?

Comment: why `unsigned char *` ? it is convertible to `const char*`

Comment: In my rhapsody code everywhere we use OMstring only and the function readstream() takes unsigned Char *

Comment: Wait a second, do you mean to _modify_ the OMString object via that readStream() call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation ( http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rhp.frameworks.doc%2Ftopics%2Frhp_r_fw_omstring_class.html ), you can always use operator [] to build yourself a small utility function that converts an OMString object to an std::string and then use std::string's c_str() method to get at it's const char* content:

```
#include <string>
#include <omstring.h>

    std::string omStringToStdString( const OMString& in )
    {
        std::string result( in.GetLength(), '\0' );

        for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < result.length(); ++i )
        {
            result[ i ] = in[ i ];
        }

        return result;
    }
```

EDIT: Apparently OMString has an operator* that returns a **const char*** pointer to the string's content: ( http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rhp.frameworks.doc%2Ftopics%2Frhp_r_fw_operator_customize.html ), so you don't actually need the conversion function I posted above.

EDIT #2: Ok, on re-reading the OP's question, I'm now getting the impression that he doesn't want to read from an OMString but to write to one. In that case, the OMString::GetBuffer() method gives you direct access to the object's internal buffer. Be careful though, you can easily end up corrupting the OMString object's internal state if you write more characters than the buffer has space for (and possibly if you insert \0 chars before the actual end of the buffer).

Comment: Here readStream puts some valid string "Hello" into MachineType so I cant use GetBuffer

Comment: @Sijith Why not? If readStream() is going to write something into the array it is passed a pointer to, and GetBuffer() gives you a char* pointer to the internal character array of the OMString object represented by your MachineType variable, then it would seem to me that you most certainly can use GetBuffer() in that way. Of course, you'd still have to reinterpret_cast the return value of GetBuffer() to unsigned char* if that's what your readStream() method wants.
Please clarify if I've misunderstood your problem.